# How to load an Iframe without flickering

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery, iframe

This is my Iframe

```
 <iframe id="iframe1" frameborder="0" style=" width: 379px;
    height:110%;" src="frmChatRequest.aspx"
    scrolling="no" runat="server">
 </iframe>
```

This is the meta tag (in frmChatRequest.aspx page (See in Iframe)) which I used to load the page in Iframe

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10" />
```

But the page flickers every time it loads, I want to use spmething like updatePanel or Ajax, etc, so that it doesn't blinks when it is loaded. Or use javascipt to load the Iframe content instead of using meta tag so that it doesn't blink. Help me Please

Comment: Check the code in frmChatRequest.aspx. There might be some table or image which takes time to load. Because of which there might be flicker./

Comment: Cmon Dude, it's only a gridview, what should I do show that it appears that only new data is being added

Answer (score 1):

You can use a javascript function as below

```
function loadiframe(siteurl) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById("iframe").src = siteurl;
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: You meant that I should replace siteurl with frmChatRequest.aspx??

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div>
 <img id="theimg" src="../images/myimage.png" alt="Erreur" height="100%" width="100%"/>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var theimg = document.getElementById("theimg");
  var theurl = "../images/myimage.png";
  setInterval(function() {
    theimg.src = theurl + '?t=' + new Date().getTime();
   }, 1000);
</script>
```